# Why are corporate printers so large?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, computer-hardware

I often seen printers [like this](http://www.office.xerox.com/multifunction-printer/color-multifunction/xerox-color-c60-c70/enus.html) in offices and schools. Considering how we can have printers small enough to fit on a desk, why are these printers taking up half a room? What are they capable of doing, and why do they need to be that large?

Comment: Note that significant part of the space is for storing paper, wether its in process of being used or waiting for pickup.

Comment: They are for large print jobs and can also do binding in some cases

Comment: Try printing 5,000 pages *per day,* every working day, on your desktop-sized printer, and see how long it lasts. Probably less than a day, if it was a cheap one - even if it is fast enough to actually print that many pages in one day!

Comment: Most of the volume is in the paper handling mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One requirement is serviceability and time between refills (of either ink or paper.

When printing 15 copies of a 100 page report you don't want to have to stand next to it and refill the paper and ink 10 times before it's done. Instead you want to push the button and then pick up the stack for binding later after you had your coffee.

Having components be serviceable means that you need to be able to access them or remove them. This means adding space for an arm to reach in (and possibly a head) or adding bulk for the interface of the module and the rest of the machine (or both).

Comment: Nearly all big office printers can bind paper with staples. But a close observation is that no user ever uses this feature, since the only time the counter of how many staples are left advances is when I print. And then ask me for a stapler.

Answer (score 2):

These environment requires a printer which are supposed to include photocopying, fax, scan and a risograph among other functions. [Risograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risograph) are highly needed in offices and schools for high-speed duplication of printed materials such as questionnaires, examination papers, forms, etc. The risograph can replicate a copy into 500 pages in about 2 minutes so this saves a lot of time and effort.

See its specifications below:

[image: Multi-functional Printer]

Comment: Please check the wiki link for the risograph. This is usually used by printing companies because it uses special type of paper to create a master copy and print like a roller drum into the paper. This is kinda similar to silkscreen printing but only done on paper.